# How to identify tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array of tuples that can either be in the form of:

```
(a,b,c,d)
```

or:

```
(b,c,d)
```

When iterating over the array elements, how do I know which kind of tuple that element is?

Comment: Are you referring to the difference in size?

Comment: could you be more clear! can you please add more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`len(tuple)` will yield the length of the tuple, which you could use to differentiate your two types.